# How to convert array to string in codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, string, codeigniter

I am new to PHP.

I want to convert this array;

```
array(2) {  
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#24 (1) { 
        ["item"]=> string(1) "2" 
    } 
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#25 (1) { 
        ["item"]=> string(1) "1" 
    } 
}
```

to string like this

`string(1) "2", string(2)"1", string(3)"0"`...

What is the way to do this?

Note: i try add to "row()" in php code. but always single result.
for example: only **string(1)"2"**

Comment: Where is the object coming from?  Is it from the database?  Are you trying to get those strings in a loop?  Do you want one string or multiple strings?

Comment: Have you looking for the print_r function ?

Comment: Do you *literally* want `string(2)"1"`?  That looks like the output of `var_dump`, but the string's length is incorrect.

Comment: Exactly, And i think OP unaware of this

Comment: @RocketHazmat i want multiple strings. for example: $this->db->where('item', $data->$item); but my query is array.

Comment: @YankıKüçük: So you want to look for `item IN (2,1)` (or `item=2 OR item=1`), is that what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking something weird. But here is an answer:

let say `$arr` is your

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#24 (1) { ["item"]=> string(1) "2" } 
[1]=> object(stdClass)#25 (1) { ["item"]=> string(1) "1" } }
```

then your code to convert it into that string you mentioned will be:

```
$str=''; $idx=0;
foreach ($arr as $obj) {
  $str.=($idx==0?'':', ').'string ('.$idx++.') "'.$obj->item.'"';
}
```

Now you have your weird string in `$str` var.

Or if my first weird guess is wrong. Here is another that has more sense to me, but not asked by you:

```
foreach ($arr as $obj) {
   echo $obj->item; // or do whatever you want with this value which is string type
}
```

Comment: Exactly, And i think OP unaware of this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks you have an array object, you need to use a foreach loop here, and your array values are "2", "1". Not `string(1) "2"` , `string(1) "1"`, You use a **var_dump** so the arrays shows with the type and length.

```
array(2) {  
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#24 (1) { 
        ["item"]=> string(1) "2" 
    } 
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#25 (1) { 
        ["item"]=> string(1) "1" 
    } 
}
```

To get each value using foreach, see the below example, let your array name is `$arr`.

```
foreach($arr as $val){
    echo $val->item; 
}
```

This will display the array values as: **"2", "1".**

Comment: but i cant use database query. for example: $this->db->where('item', $data4->$item);

Comment: you want to use them like array(2,1).

Comment: simply use $s = implode(",", (array)$arr);. I think it works